# Retrieving list of Google+ comunity activites

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api, google-plus

I am using the **google+** api to retrieve a list of community posts.

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/111449227367642341024/activities/public?key={YOUR_API_KEY}');
$response = json_decode($data, true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
```

But it throws error like

> Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

I have also passed api-key but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible problem number one:**

[Activities: list](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/list)

> List all of the activities in the specified collection for a
>   particular **user**.

Note: 111449227367642341024 does not appear to be a valid Google+ user id so that doesn't work I am going to assume that you changed it

**Possible problem number two:**

The code you have posted does not contain an API key you say you have passed it.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/111449227367642341024/activities/public?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Possible problem number three:**

Also make sure that you have the Google+ API enabled in google developers console.

Comment: No you cant read posts from a community.   As the documentation states its for a particular "User".  There is no way to get data for a community.

Comment: Ok. Can i have post of collections?

Comment: My guess is probably not as the only "collection" you can send is public.  I am reading this directly from the documentation.